# Given a set S and n subsets of S: Find the subset of each of the n subsets, up to k elements, such that the union is maximized

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, optimization, algorithms, discrete-optimization

Given a set S, and n subsets of S, which may be overlapping or disjoint:
Find up to k elements from each of the n given subsets, such that the union of the elements selected from each subset is maximized.

In other words, if S = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, for n=3 the subsets given may look like {1,3,6,7,9,10}, {1,2,3}, {2,3,6,7,8}. Find a subset of each of these subsets such that the union of them is maximized. So the solution for k=3 may look like {7,9,10} {1,2,3} {6,8}. I am struggling to understand the best algorithm for this.

Another way to think about it is there are N provider points and C consumer points and each provider point can form an edge with up to k consumer points. Given the sets of consumer points that are reachable for each N, find the subset of consumer points with up to k elements, to connect to for each provider in order to maximize the number of consumer points connected to a provider.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this question by reformulating it using graph theory in a few ways.

**Solution 1: Network flow**

Let us create a bipartite graph with edge capacities with $|S|$ elements of set $S$ on partition $A$ and $n$ sets on partition $B$. Let there be an $1$ capacity edge from an element in $A$ to a set in $B$ if the set contains the element. Now to this bipartite graph, we add two vertices, source vertex and sink vertex. The source vertex is connected to all vertices in $B$ with $k$ capacity edges and the sink vertex is connected to all vertices in $A$ with $1$ capacity edges. Now this is a [flow network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network) and the maximum integer flow to this network will show which elements to choose in each set. This can be solved using the [Ford–Fulkerson algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) in $O(Ef)$ time. Since the maximum flow $f$ cannot be greater than $|S|$, the algorithm will run in $O(E |S|) = O(n|S|^2)$.

**Solution 2: Bipartite matching**

Let us create a bipartite graph with $|S|$ elements of set $S$ on partition $A$ and $n$ sets repeated $k$ times on partition $B$. Let there be an edge from an element in $A$ to a set in $B$ if the set contains the element. Now a maximum matching in this bipartite graph will give us the set of elements to choose in each set. The Bipartite matching problem can be solved by [Hopcroft–Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) in $O(E \sqrt{V}) = O(n|k||S|\sqrt{n|k|+|S|})$ time.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  For $i\in [n]$, let $S_i$ be the given subset.  For $i\in [n]$ and $j\in S_i$, let binary decision variable $x_{i,j}$ indicate whether element $j$ is selected from $S_i$. For $j\in S$, let binary decision variable $y_j$ indicate whether $j$ appears in the union.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_{j\in S} y_j$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_{j\in S_i} x_{i,j} &\le k &&\text{for $i\in [n]$} \tag1\\
y_j &\le \sum_{i\in [n]} x_{i,j} &&\text{for $j\in S$} \tag2
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ enforces selecting at most $k$ elements from $S_i$.  Constraint $(2)$ enforces the logical implication $y_j \implies \vee_{i\in [n]} x_{i,j}$.